# Wicket Error Message: Cannot instantiate the type TableTree<Zustaendigkeit,String>

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to build a Wicket "TableTree", when I use following code

```
public class TableTreePage extends WebPage{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList<IColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>>();
private ZustaendigkeitsProvider zustProvider = new ZustaendigkeitsProvider();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public TableTreePage(){
    columns.add((IColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>) new PropertyColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>(
            Model.of("Institut / Firma"), "institutfirma"));
    columns.add((IColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>) new PropertyColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>(
            Model.of("Erhebung"), "erhebung"));
    columns.add((IColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>) new PropertyColumn<Zustaendigkeit, String>(
            Model.of("Rolle / Funktion"), "rollefunktion"));

    TableTree<Zustaendigkeit, String> tree = new TableTree<Zustaendigkeit, String>("myTableTree", columns, zustProvider, 100);
    //Error comes here

}}
```

I get this Error: *Cannot instantiate the type TableTree*

I saw that some other questions belonged to a simular error, which was caused because they tried to implement a List, which is an Interface. Since I declared my ArrayList and Zustaendigkeit is an actual class I don't know where the problem is.

**Edit:** I noticed that TableTree is an abstract Class. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.tree.DefaultTableTree

Comment: What's the difference / advantage?

Comment: It's a generic implementation, which implements the `newContentComponent` method, thus it can be instantiated. Also it  applies some CSS for a common table look.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solution found.
In order to make it work, you have to write:

```
TableTree<Zustaendigkeit, String> tree = new TableTree<Zustaendigkeit, String>("myTableTree", columns, zustProvider, 100){//unimplementet Methods import}
```